# Is it ok to use DTO annotations like request models for Lint not for validation?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have request models for creating or updating endpoints with annotations attributes for Swagger. Frontend wants to add the same annotations to DTO which API returns, because Lint can't initialize values (required fields for example).

So, is it good practice to create the same DTO with annotations (not for validation, for Lint more) like request models?

Comment: Could you post some codes so we can understand clearly.